# How to create spring bean in xml for java annotated code

Tags: java, spring

How to create spring bean in xml for below code?

```
@Bean
public XYZServiceClient getXYZServiceClient() {
  return new XYZServiceClientBuilder().withparamA(paramA)
            .withparamB(ParamB)
            .build();
}
```

Comment: Simply exclude your @Configuration from scanning e.g. exclude from `ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.example")`  and then use [Spring beans factory method](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-beans-factory-methods) with XML

Answer (score 2):

The "beans" are supposed to have either a constructor or `setXxx()` methods. That's how you usually set all the values.

Your code uses a builder, which doesn't match any of these patterns (which is weird for Service, whose params should usually be passed into constructor). For such custom code you'd need to implement a `FactoryBean`:

```
class XYZServiceClientBean implements FactoryBean<XYZServiceClient> {
    public XYZServiceClient getObject() throws Exception {
        return new XYZServiceClientBuilder().withparamA(paramA)
                .withparamB(ParamB)
                .build();
    }
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return XYZServiceClient.class;
    }
    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And describe *this* as a bean in XML. The `FactoryBean` can then accept all the arguments in its own constructor:

```
<bean class="some.package.XYZServiceClientBean">
    <constructor-arg ... />
</bean>
```

And then pass them to the actual `XYZServiceClient` in `getObject()`.

But really if you have control over your code you should use the constructor. You can use it with `autowire="byType"` if there are too many params and you don't want to explicitly list them. This is also the shortest way to explicitly declare a bean in Spring.